# KnockoutJS - Some click bindings firing on enter pressed

Tags: knockout.js

I have a .net webforms page with a large knockout viewmodel and I'm toggling some div's being hidden or changing css if certain div's are clicked.  I also have a number of different event handlers and some computed's that cause ajax lookups.

The issue is when I press enter in any input box on the page, a function in the viewmodel fires which is bound to a click handler on a div and also another that is bound to a button inside this div.  If I remove the click binding on the div, the entire page is post which makes me think it is related to default button behaviour.

I've tried to recreate the bulk of the functionality in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yKdnE/) and the code below, however, this isn't recreating the issue.

**html**

```
<body>

    <div style="width:30%; float:left;">
        <div id="div1" class="divClass" data-bind="click: showDiv1, css: { active: div1Visible }">
            <h2>Div 1</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="div2" class="divClass" data-bind="click: showDiv2, css: { active: !div1Visible() }">
            <h2>Div 2</h2>
            <button id="randomButton">Random Button</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="width:70%; float:left;" data-bind="visible: div1Visible">
            <input  placeholder="name" 
                id="nameSearch" 
                type="text" 
                name="nameSearch"
                data-bind="value:nameSearch, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: {keyup: doSearch}"
                autocomplete="off"  
                />
         <input  placeholder="address" 
                id="addressSearch" 
                type="text" 
                name="addressSearch"
                data-bind="value:addressSearch, valueUpdate: 'afterkeydown', event: {keyup: doSearch}"
                autocomplete="off"  
               />
            <button id="resetButton">Reset</button>
        <div>
            <input id="grid" value="pretend I am a grid" />
        </div>
    </div>
        <div style="width:70%; float:left;" data-bind="visible: !div1Visible()">
            Should be hidden unless div 1 inactive
            <div data-bind="text: message"></div>
        </div>

</body>
```

**js**

```
function MyViewModel() {
    // Data
    var self = this;
    self.div1Visible = ko.observable(true);
    self.nameSearch = ko.observable('');
    self.addressSearch = ko.observable('');
    self.message = ko.observable('');

    self.showDiv1 = function() {
    self.div1Visible(true);
    };    
    self.showDiv2 = function() {
             self.div1Visible(false);
    };

     self.doSearch = function (data, event) {
        var charCode = (event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode);
        if (charCode === 40) {
             $('#grid').focus();
        }
        return false;
    };

     self.quickSearch = ko.computed(function () {
         if(self.nameSearch() || self.addressSearch()) {
        //do some ajax grid binding if any values in search inputs
             $('#grid').val('found values');
         }

    }, self).extend({ throttle: 400 });

     self.searchHasValues = ko.computed(function () {
        return self.nameSearch() || self.addressSearch();
    });

    self.setMessage = function() {
         self.message('Shows when random button clicked');
    };

    self.resetSearch = function() {
        self.nameSearch('');
        self.addressSearch('');
        $('#grid').val('searchReset');
    };

}
window.viewModel = new MyViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

  $('#randomButton').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                viewModel.setMessage();
            });
  $('#resetButton').click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                viewModel.resetSearch();
            });
```

**css**

```
.divClass {
    background-color: #ccc;   
    height:200px;
    padding:10px;
}
.active {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I am finding it hard to identify exactly what the problem is, but I do know a bit about asp.net webforms so I'm going to have a guess here.

- You are using asp.net webforms, which generally wrap the entire body
  of a page in a single form.
- In any HTML form, when a text input has
  focus and you press the enter button, the click handler of the first
  visible button is executed.
- Your button is contained inside of a div
  which has it's own click event handler. The click event firing on the
  button is bubbling up and executing any click event handlers on all
  of its parent elements right to the top of the DOM.

You may be able to solve this by attaching a keypress/keydown event handler on your input elements. Inside that handler, prevent the event from bubbling up only when the enter button is pressed.

Comment: I might try to move it into a mvc project and see if it still happens.  Also will try a handler on all input items

Comment: Having moved to MVC long ago I would definitely recommend it. Much of the webforms 'magic' that is intended to make things easier actually makes things more difficult when it comes to using client side frameworks such as knockout. I wish you well!